# Distance between Sprinkler head and Air condition system

Tags: sprinkler-system, fire-sprinkler

I'm planning to add Sprinkler system in office area which have a central air condition system.
Does code specify how close air condition can be to the sprinklers head?
What does minimum distance between sprinkler head and Air condition system should be?

Comment: Code questions are tough to answer as code tends to vary from country to country, state to state, city to city.  If you can provide location information you may get lucky and have someone that knows your specific situation.  That said if you can reword your question to get a more general suggestion/best practice answer that may be more doable.

Comment: I don't think there'd be a problem, unless the ducting obstructed the spray from the nozzle or interfered with the operation of the sprinkler head in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioning units can get water on them - save any internal electronics which almost always have guard/protection/enclosure.  I can't foresee any local code that would care.

Answer (score 0):

Code in my area requires you use a professional to install the sprinkler.
The pro will know the exact details.  It also depends which part of the air conditioner is involved.